# How to adjust size of gridview for different size of devices

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am using a gridview to get filenames from database in asp.net.how to reduce size of gridview so it looks good in mobile device

Comment: Try to add image to what you want

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a Responsive grid view then i suggest to use Bootstrap library to do this

Comment: This should not be answer. This should be comment.